# Does C# support type inference of the return type?

Tags: c#, type-inference

This is just a curiousity about if there is a fundamental thing stopping something like this  (or correct me if there's already some way):

```
public TTo Convert<TTo, TFrom>(TFrom from)
{
    ...
}
```

Called like this:

```
SomeType someType = converter.Convert(someOtherType);
```

Comment: @aqwert: He's asking why they can't add such a feature.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because what would happen if you did this?

```
static void M(int x){}
static void M(double x){}
static T N<T>() {}
...
M(N());
```

Now what is T? int or double?

It's all very easy to solve the problem when you know what the type you're assigning to *is*, but much of the time *the type you're assigning to is the thing you're trying to figure out in the first place*.

Reasoning from inside to outside is hard enough. Reasoning from outside to inside is far more difficult, and *doing both at the same time is extremely difficult*. If it is hard for the *compiler* to understand what is going on, imagine how hard it is for the human trying to read, understand and debug the code when inferences can be made both *from* and *to* the type of the context of an expression. This kind of inference makes programs *harder* to understand, not *easier*, and so it would be a bad idea to add it to C#.

Now, that said, C# *does* support this feature with lambda expressions. When faced with an overload resolution problem in which the lambda can be bound two, three, or *a million* different ways, we bind it two, three or a million different ways and then evaluate those million different possible bindings to determine which one is "the best". This makes overload resolution at least NP-HARD in C#, and it took me the better part of a year to implement. We were willing to make that investment because (1) lambdas are awesome, and (2) most of the time people write programs that can be analyzed in a reasonable amount of time and can be understood by humans. So it was worth the cost. But in general, that kind of advanced analysis is not worth the cost.

Comment: has the idea of hooks/intercepters built into the compiler ever been floated? i.e. if you wanted to make code like my question compile, you could handle/resolve the error that halts the compiler

Comment: @Gabriel: Sure, people ask for that all the time. If you're looking for a language which allows you to change the fundamental behaviour of the language, consider Python; I hear it is good for that.

Comment: that wouldn't compile because `T` isn't deducible in this context.

Comment: Why don't we declare that "The type arguments for method bla-bla cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly." only and only in case of "M(N())"? Why can't we omit specifying these generic params in case of "bool result = N(request)"?

Comment: @donRumatta: Sure, we can come up with one-off special cases all day, and indulging them gets the spec longer and longer, and the implementation of overload resolution gets more and more complicated. "Does this feature break overload resolution?" is already the hardest question that must be answered when proposing a new C# language feature; the design team is loath to make that worse unless there is a truly compelling benefit. Making special cases to handle narrow scenarios is not enough bang for the considerable bucks it requires.

Comment: @EricLippert, I understand your point of view, but traditionally once in a year I meet this limitation and several other ones and get some body parts burning)

Answer (score 1):

C# expressions always* have a fixed type, regardless of their surroundings.

You're asking for an expression whose type is determined by whatever it's assigned to; that would violate this principle.

*) except for lambda expressions, function groups, and the `null` literal.

Comment: **If** the C# language was designed such that "the surroundings" included an l-value type then it would be possible... so why wasn't it? ;-) I don't really want/need an answer for that, but it might be more inline with the posters intent (and your post comment).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Java, in C# type reference doesn't base on the return type. And don't ask me why, Eric Lippert had answered these "why can't C# ..." questions:

> because no one ever designed, specified, implemented, tested,
>   documented and shipped that feature

Comment: It is also much more complicated. Imagine when the result is *not* used or when the result type "target" conforms to multiple overloads...

Comment: @pst: If the result is not used or matches a few overloads, they(the c# team) have to define a rule, just like overlording M(object o) M(int o) in C# currently. This design makes sense(Java uses it).

Comment: When that happens you would get something like SFINAE of C++. Because we really need another turing tarpit to play for fun.